# Have there been any titled North Korean players?

Tags: famous-players, titles

I recently played against a player with a North Korean flag on Chess.com.  I assume they just picked that flag for a laugh or something, but it did get me wondering; have there been any titled North Korean players?  If not, have any North Koreans achieved any recognition in chess?

Answer (score 13):

I tried searching for players by countries in [ratings.fide.com](https://ratings.fide.com)'s advanced search feature but i couldn't seem to find the north korea country there

After some research, I found this player: [Roza Lallemand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roza_Lallemand) which is a french GM from north korea

I don't know if this counts as she is born in North Korea but she is a french player

Comment: "I don't know if this counts as she is born in North Korea but she is a french player" According to that wiki article, she emigrated to the Soviet Union as a child, and was trained to play chess in a school there - and wound up moving to France after she met her husband.

Comment: Kind of funny that her surname after marriage literally means "The German" in French. The NK-born Soviet-French German

Comment: Can you actually pick a country in chess.com? I thought this was geolocated...

Comment: North Koreans have essentially no internet access.  There are very few computers accessible for personal use, what few are accessible are only available for powerful people, and even they are behind NK's version of The Great Firewall.  I think Chess.com geolocates to pick a default flag, but then allows you to choose.

Comment: 'was a French chess player of North Korean origin who was raised in the Soviet Union' --> wow

Comment: Roza was from South Korea, not North Korea.

Comment: @Kerindor Wikipedia says "born in North Korea" though. Are you claiming the reference they cite is wrong?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Wikipedia contradicts itself. In the main text it says "Roza Te was born in North Korea in 1961". In the box on the right hand side under the picture it says "Born Roza Te
8 August 1961
South Korea"
Given they emigrated to the Soviet Union I would say North Korea is more likely, but due to the contradiction  Wikipedia can't be taken as an authoritative source in this case/

Comment: @IanBush Good point. The cited references confirm North Korea though; for instance there's https://deces.matchid.io/search?advanced=true&fuzzy=false&ln=Te&bd=1961&dage=47&size=n_60_n .

Comment: @FedericoPoloni as I read it it's actually reference [8] at http://www.echecs.asso.fr/eem/eem95.pdf . In fact the Wikipedia article looks like a translation of this in parts.

Comment: @IanBush I have edited Wikipedia to fix the mistake.